# I am unable to find the Purple block named call resetform in MIT App Inventor 2

Tags: app-inventor

I'm building a Pizza Party app in MIT app inventor 2, I need to find the purple block named call resetForm but I am unable to. I belive it is under the procedure section of blocks but I could be wrong.[what I am building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zTuU.png)
[image]

- this is what I am making and you can see at the bottom of the InsertDataInTable procedure it calls resetForm.

I tried to make a procedure, so then when I called it, it worked[what I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwmUL.png),
[image]

but when I tried to delete the procedure the call also went away. I am assuming that I have to put code in the procedure I created or else the code will not work. Please help me.

Comment: You might try using cloudDB: https://groups.google.com/g/mitappinventortest/c/hOx-n14lkBs/m/Nq2OIuyAAQAJ, or the Spreadsheet component: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dwiY1GYFGMd1pEeCl6NvGp3q3-G2hKEm_YyFRDekDDc/edit?usp=sharing , for your Pizza Party app project instead

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** According to [the tutorial](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/pizzaparty), Google has stopped supporting Google Fusion Tables (used in Pizza Party).

**TL;DR**: Your assumption is correct.

Procedures (functions) are just little containers for code so that there is less duplicate or redundant code. Since these containers are used by referencing them, if they are empty (or deleted) then they are just as useful as if they weren't there. For more information, I suggest you read [this](https://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/concepts/procedures).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).